# Hive Distinct to sample certain number of column values

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

My aim is to return the data in a way where the 'name' column has at max 3 distinct values.
My table is like this

```
id, name, year

1, John, 2012

2, Jake, 2012

3, Jenna, 2013

1, John, 2013

4, Tyler, 2012

5, Jenna, 2013
```

I need to do distinct on name field in such a way that the output contains atmax 3 unique values in name field. There can be repetitions due to different values in other fields and those can come in the output as well. Example if the set the threshold as 3, then we the output should contain only 3 distinct names with repetition allowed.

Output I need is

```
id, name, year

1, John, 2012

2, Jake, 2012

3, Jenna, 2013

1, John, 2013

5, Jenna, 2013
```

How to achieve this kind of result with distinct? Because distinct would identify 3 distinct records if I want all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'John' name, 2012 `year` UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Jake', 2012 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Jenna', 2013 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'John', 2013 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Tyler', 2012 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Jenna', 2013
)
SELECT id, name, `year` FROM (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name) rank
    FROM sample_table
) t WHERE rank <= 3;
```

**Query results**

[image]

For random sampling, you might consider below.

```sql
SELECT id, name, `year` FROM (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY hash) rnk FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(rand()) OVER (PARTITION BY name) hash
      FROM sample_table
  ) t
) t WHERE rnk <= 3;
```

This will show different result from above.

[image]